# -wise, -mente, -ment: How many languages use the "mind" metaphor for adjectives made adverbs?

Tags: etymology, comparative-linguistics, adverbs

When I noticed that English, Spanish, Italian, and French use the "mind" metaphor to turn certain adjectives into adverbs (not all, *cf* "-ly" from English). That is, as it was explained to me by a Spanish professor, "*Rapidamente* literally means 'of fast mind.'" I did a brief search to see what other languages did this this morning after I realized that "-wise" is no different.

The mind metaphor doesn't seem to be universal. I understand that modern Hebrew does it like "in [noun-form of adjective]," Swedish "-ligen," as a word on its own, seems to mean "literally." I can't tell the etymology of "-о́" in Russian, nor "地" for Chinese. German "-erweise" comes from "way/manner."

Two coupled questions: **How many languages use the mind metaphor for adverbial adjectives, and why do those that do, do?**

Comment: Swedish _-ligen_ is not a word in itself and doesn’t mean ‘literally’. It is the adverbial form of the adjectival suffix _-lig_, which is cognate with English _-ly_, so originally meaning ‘body/shape/form’ (as opposed to ‘mind’, though still fairly close). Chinese 地 _de_ is simply a particle; it has no certain etymology beyond that (possibly same word as 的 _de_, which itself is of unknown etymology, or possibly from 地 _dì_ ‘place’).

Answer (score 5):

#### Quite a few, and they mostly inherited it from Proto-Romance.

In Classical Latin (the Latin written by Vergil and Cicero), there were a few different ways of forming adverbs, using the suffixes *-e* and *-iter*. For example, "sad" was *tristis*, and "sadly" was *triste*.

In Vulgar Latin (the Latin spoken on the streets of Rome), however, these suffixes were rare except in a few specific formulas. Instead of doing something "sadly" *triste*, you would do it "with a sad mind" *tristi mente*. Eventually, people didn't think of the *mente* part as a separate word meaning "mind" any more—it was just something you stuck onto adjectives to make adverbs.

And thus we end up with forms like French *tristement*, Spanish and Italian *tristemente*, and so on. Most Romance languages now form their adverbs this way, just because they inherited it from Vulgar Latin/Proto-Romance.

English "-wise", as far as I know, is a separate issue. It comes from "wise", an archaic noun meaning "way" or "method". And it's now used mostly on *nouns*, not on adjectives, to form adverbs meaning "pertaining to".

Comment: Really _-ly_ is closer to the Romance way than _-wise_ – it refers to shape/form/body rather than mind, but other than that it’s the same.

Comment: Really? I'd have expected *-modo* to play a role here.

Comment: I agree that "(other)wise" is a separate issue. But etymologically "wise" in the sense "manner, the way something is perceived" (German Weise) is from the same root as "wise" "full of wisdom".